# Changing the Utc Date to Local Date using moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

i'm using moment.js with timezones for date manipulation in a webapp. i'm storing all the dates in UTC and return them to UI as UTC. I'm having the timezone of the user. i want to convert the UTC time to the local Users time zone.

```
var timezone = "America/New_York";
var utcDate = "2013-10-16T10:31:59.0537721Z";

var localDate = moment(utcDate).utc().tz(timezone).format()
```

When i try to do this i'm getting wrong time. not sure how to get this working with moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
moment.utc(utcDate).tz(timezone).format()
```

But it shouldn't matter.  They should both produce:  `"2013-10-16T06:31:59-04:00"`.

It works for me, running on Chrome 30, so it's probably browser related.

If you're running Moment.js 2.3.1 or earlier on IE8, then it's a side effect of issue [#1175](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1175), which was fixed in 2.4.0.  Updating to the latest version should solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `+` operator to get unix time, then:

```
moment(+moment.utc(utcDate))
```

How it works:

- `moment.utc(String)` parses the string and returns a moment object set to UTC timezone.
- `+` returns the unix offset in milliseconds for the moment obejct
- `moment(Number)` creates a new moment object in the user's local time zone, using the passed in unix offset.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because downvoting without specifying a reason is useless.

Answer (score 4):

for anyone having the same problem:

your date iso format should contain the timezone. here is the format allowed by momentjs:

```
YYYY-MMM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00
```

notice the +00:00 mean it is UTC

example

```
moment('2014-10-03T09:31:18+00:00').format()
```

will terturn

```
"2014-10-03T17:31:18+08:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't know the timezone, you get the client offset and use like this,

```
let utcTime = "2017-02-02 08:00:13.567";
var offset = moment().utcOffset();
var localText = moment.utc(utcTime).utcOffset(offset).format("L LT");
```

Try this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahim373/L0gcL0td/)